# UITableView with "static" headers

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I got a UITableView with several headers and with clear backgrounds over a customized tableview background.

The problem comes when scrolling the tableview and the default functionality where the headers stays at the top of the tableview to indicate what section is "active". Because the headerview has a clear background the text in the rows beneath the headerview is visible through the headers and it looks really bad.

Is there some sort of setting for the tableview to make the headers "follow" the rows when scrolling and disable this default behaviour?

I hope you guys understand my problem, I can provide screenshots if the problem isn't good enough explained.

Comment: Can you give screen shots of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one solution:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
       CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = 40;
   if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=sectionHeaderHeight&&scrollView.contentOffset.y>=0) {
       scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
   } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>=sectionHeaderHeight) {
       scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-sectionHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0);
   }
}
```

However it will have a bit of flicker while header reaches to top.

One more soultion is to make Grouped table view.

One more thing is to add a section with zero rows at the top and simply use the footer of the previous section as a header for the next.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change this behaviour.

I think your best option would be to not use the built in headers, but implement custom ones as `UITableViewCell`s and return them interleaved into the content from `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally weird and I happen to discover this accidentally. on your storyboard change click on your tableview and change the style of the table from plain to grouped! When I did this the headers where scrolling up and down just like tableview cells